# play_licensing throws AIDL error with downloader_library for APK Expansion with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, apk-expansion-files

I tried to use the APK Expansion libs zip_file and downloader_library (which requires play_licensing). zip_file worked fine since it has no dependencies, but play_licensing throws an error when I try a Gradle sync.

Android Studio spits out this error log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateGoogleDebugSources, :app:libs:downloader_library:generateDebugSources, :app:libs:play_licensing:generateDebugSources, :app:libs:zip_file:generateDebugSources]
Information:/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/TogetherTime/app/libs/play_licensing/aidl/ILicenseResultListener.aidl:21 interface ILicenseResultListener should be declared in a file called com/android/vending/licensing/ILicenseResultListener.aidl.
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/TogetherTime/app/libs/play_licensing/aidl/ILicensingService.aidl
Error:(19) couldn't find import for class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicenseResultListener
Error:(19) Execution failed for task ':app:libs:play_licensing:compileReleaseAidl'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.0.3/aidl -p/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-19/framework.aidl -o/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/TogetherTime/app/libs/play_licensing/build/source/aidl/release -I/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/TogetherTime/app/libs/play_licensing/aidl -I/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/TogetherTime/app/libs/play_licensing/src/release/aidl -d/var/folders/y6/g0d5m3f94rxdvq5myp53d9k80000gn/T/aidl662748145109587430.d /Users/faiz/Projects/Android/TogetherTime/app/libs/play_licensing/aidl/ILicensingService.aidl

Error Code:
  1

Output:
/Users/faiz/Projects/Android/TogetherTime/app/libs/play_licensing/aidl/ILicensingService.aidl:19: couldn't find import for class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicenseResultListener
```

I haven't modified any of the libraries, but since they weren't built for Gradle, I copied over a build.gradle from another project and modified them accordingly.

**downloader_library/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile project(':app:libs:play_licensing')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

**play_licensing/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['aidl']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 3
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using Android Studio 0.5.1 and gradle 0.9.0 with build tools 19.0.3

Comment: Please mark makovkastar's answer as correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem and found solution for it. Just create a new package with the name `com.android.vending.licensing` under the `aidl` folder and move your aidl files there:

[image]

P.S. you also have to add empty `<application />` tags to `AndroidManifest.xml` of play_licensing and downloader_library modules. And `compile project(':PlayLicensing')` to the dependencies tag of the `build.gradle` of the downloader_library

Comment: It compiles, but my licensing service is still not working. Always dies end on MyLicenseCheckerCallback.applicationError(int errorCode) and without errorCode available. Any idea?